# What happened to Darth Maul?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, darth-maul

In the Clone Wars TV show it is revealed that:

> Darth Maul survived his bifurcation at the hands of Obi-wan and managed to escape Naboo. Years later, during the Clone Wars, he resurfaces with robot legs.  With the help of his brother he gains control of Mandalore. Then Palpatine arrives, kills his brother and forcibly returns Darth Maul to his service.

What happens next? Is there any non-Legends canon that indicates what happens to Darth Maul after the Clone Wars?

Comment: There currently is no canon answer to *what happens to Darth Maul after the Clone Wars*, but @phantom42's answer does a good job of explaining, without too many spoilers, what happens next.

Comment: My god, just when you thought the *Star Wars* saga couldn't get any stupider....

Comment: Hey, doesn't this violate the Sith Rule of Two...its now Two and a Half!

Comment: @Oldcat - NBC already have Charlie Sheen slated for the remake; Two and a Half Sith

Comment: Well the annoying star wars rebels is revealing Hondo,Rex and Asoka!!!
And vader has also arrived. You can see the trailer:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj5FbXYLaP8 Maybe Maul will Return.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We now know a decent amount about Maul's activities towards the end of the Clone Wars, and beyond:

- As phantom42 [notes in his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73480/31051), the canon comic series *Darth Maul: Son of Dathomir* sees Maul escape from Sidious' custody (where we last saw him in *The Clone Wars* show), capturing Dooku and Grievous and bringing them to Dathomir in an attempt to lure out and kill Sidious. This (inevitably) fails, and Maul flees with what remains of his loyal Death Watch
- The next time we see him, Ahsoka has tracked him to Mandalore. [She takes some clones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144912/31051) to hunt him down, but the operation is interrupted by Order 66; Maul subsequently escapes:

  > She should have been at the Temple. She should have been with Anakin. She should have helped. Instead, she'd been on Mandalore, almost entirely alone, surrounded by clones and confusion and blaster fire. Maul had escaped, of course. She'd had the opportunity to kill him, but had chosen to save Rex instead. She didn’t regret that, couldn’t regret it, but the mischief and worse that Maul might wreak in a galaxy with no Jedi to protect it gnawed at her.
  >
  > <sup>*Ahsoka*</sup>
- At some point he evidently got himself on Vader's radar, since the Inquisitor known as [Eighth Brother](http://www.starwars.com/databank/eighth-brother-inquisitor) was sent by him to take him out:

  > Dispatched by Darth Vader, he was sent to Malachor to attempt to find and capture Maul
- As revealed in the *Rebels* episode "Twilight of the Apprentice", he somehow managed to get to Malachor; he claims that his ship crashed, stranding him there:

  > **Ezra:** You live here? Alone in the dark?
  >
  > **Maul:** Not by choice. My ship crashed; I'm trapped, marooned, I've had to scrounge and scrape to survive.
  >
  > <sup>*Star Wars: Rebels* Season 2 Episode 20: "Twilight of the Apprentice Part 1"</sup>

  However, considering his end goal, that seems a half-truth at best:

  > **Maul:** [Ezra] is activating the temple; or, more precisely, this battlestation, which I shall use to exact my revenge on all my enemies!
  > <sup>*Star Wars: Rebels* Season 2 Episode 21: "Twilight of the Apprentice Part 2"</sup>

  He escapes at the end of the episode.
- Over the course of two (non-sequential) episodes of *Rebels*' third season, "Holocrons of Fate" and "Visions and Voices", Maul learns that his hated enemy Obi-Wan Kenobi survived Order 66 and is hiding on [a desert planet with two suns](http://www.starwars.com/databank/tatooine).
- This comes to a head in the season 3 episode "Twin Suns", in which Maul tracks Obi-Wan down on Tatooine.

  > They duel, and Maul is killed

Answer (score 12):

Yes, well sort of. [Star Wars: Darth Maul - Son of Dathomir](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir) is considered fully canon. It explains the events running through the end of the Clone Wars, but there is nothing yet describing what happens *after* the Clone Wars.

Per Wookieepedia:

> Son of Dathomir is an adaptation of unproduced scripts from Star Wars: The Clone Wars, which would have been part of the television show's sixth season had the series not been cancelled in 2013. Although thirteen episodes from the sixth season were released as "The Lost Missions" on March 7, 2014, the episodes that Son of Dathomir were based on were not completed and therefore not released as actual episodes. The story is part of The Clone Wars Legacy line.

They provide a general synopsis:

> The series is set during the Clone Wars, and is a continuation of Darth Maul's story from the show. The rogue Sith Lord, who was revealed to have survived the events of Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace in the episode "Witches of the Mist," has been captured by his former master, Darth Sidious, following the events of the episode "The Lawless." Sidious uses Maul in an attempt to draw Mother Talzin, Maul's mother and the leader of the Nightsisters, out of hiding so she can be destroyed, as Sidious considers her a potential threat to the eventual Sith domination of the galaxy. Maul confronts the Confederacy of Independent Systems and captures Count Dooku and General Grievous in pursuit of vengeance against his old master, while the Galactic Republic and Jedi Order become involved in the hopes that they can defeat Maul, Dooku, and Grievous—and, in doing so, end the Clone Wars.